# C# Regex replace all alphabets except :abc

Tags: .net, regex, string, visual-studio, c#-4.0

I have tried few combinations in C# but with no luck

I want to replace any alphabet in the string with empty string,  except where string contains :abc as the last 4 characters?

`Test123` will become `123`
`Testabc123` will become `123`
`Test:abc123` will become `123`
`Test123:abc` will become `123:abc`
`Testabc123:abc` will become `123:abc`
In the above examples,  alphabets were replaced to empty string, except where :abc were the last 4 characters, and then numbers:abc were not replaced by empty string

Can you please suggest appropriate regex?

Comment: *"I want to replace any character in the string"* are `123` not characters now?

Comment: None of your examples have `:abc` as the last 4 characters.

Comment: @chris85: The second to last example does. But it's not clear what's supposed to be going on with the final example where it clearly does not

Comment: @MattBurland Ah, missed one. Still not a good set of examples since all strings are being transformed for some reason.

Comment: examples are a little confusing vs what is asked.  is it something like /.*?(:abc)$/$1/  that you are looking for?

Comment: Corrected last example.  Essentially replace wll characters except final 4 :abc

Comment: Is `:abc` a wildcard for the last 3 characters? Why in examples 1-3 is `123` kept?

Comment: I have updated description to make it obvious what i want to achieve

Comment: Looks like you need `Regex.Replace(s, @"^\D+", "")`.

Comment: See [this demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5cD%2b&i=Test123%0d%0aTestabc123%0d%0aTest%3aabc123%0d%0aTest123%3aabc%0d%0aTestabc123%3aabc&r=&o=m).

Answer (score 0):

The regex `/^(?:(?!:abc$)\D)+/gm` *almost* works, if you replace with an empty string. As you can see [here](https://regex101.com/r/nSRu8l/8) on Regex101, it will match all parts of a string except numbers and `:abc` at the end of a line, but, for some reason, stops searching once it finds a number. So `123Test` would be unaffected, and `Test123abc` would become `123abc`.

**EDIT:** Removing the caret (start of line) fixes it, but then it also includes `:abc`, so it is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your task is still not quite clear. How many digit groups can there be in the string? Do some digits always preceed `:abc`? Does the string represent a single line or do you want it to be multiline and do replacement in each line?

If you use it just on a single string, try

`Regex.Replace(s, @"[^\d]+(\d*:abc$)|[^\d]+", "$1")`

The idea behind this one is simple: IF non-digits part ends with (optionally) some digits  and `:abc` AND is at the end of the line (such substring will be matched by the first part of the pattern before `|`) THEN preserve them (`$1`); ELSE (substring is matched by the last part of the pattern) leave nothing from this match.

P.S. Generally regular expresssions are not very good at "negative patterns" and sometimes it is easier to roll up some code. Or as [Jamie Zawinski famously quoted](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247):

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 
>   “I know, I'll use regular expressions.”    
>   Now they have two problems.

So how hard can it be?

```cs
    static string ReplaceAlphaExceptAbc(string src)
    {
        const string preserveEndPattern = ":abc";
        var res = new StringBuilder(src.Length);

        for (int i = 0; i < src.Length; i++)
        {
            var ch = src[i];
            if (Char.IsDigit(ch))
                res.Append(ch);
        }

        if (src.EndsWith(preserveEndPattern))
            res.Append(preserveEndPattern);
        return res.ToString();
    }
```